# Kafka Consumer - Fetch parameters received by listener in recover method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I am building a spring kafka consumer. I have set retry mechanism. After retries are exhausted, I would like to push the failed message to a dead letter topic.

The listen method has the below parameters

```
public void listen(@Payload Map<String, Object> conciseMap,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
        Acknowledgment ack) throws JsonProcessingException {
```

As part of the recover method , I want to fetch the conciseMap passed as input to listener map or the original message that was received by my topic. Is there a way to do it?

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(conncurrency);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
    factory.setRecoveryCallback(new RecoveryCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object recover(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            logger.debug(" In recovery callback method !!");
            ((Acknowledgment)context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT)).acknowledge();

            return null;
        }
    });
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;
}

        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        return factory;
    }

    /*
     * Retry template.
     */

    protected RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
        SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxRetryAttempts, retryableExceptions);
        return policy;
    }

    protected BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy() {
        ExponentialBackOffPolicy policy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        policy.setInitialInterval(initialRetryInterval);
        policy.setMultiplier(retryMultiplier);
        return policy;
    }

    protected RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
       RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
       template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
       template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy());
       return template;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get that converted `conciseMap` in the `RecoveryCallback`'s `RetryContext`, but you can retrieve a `ConsumerRecord` which is an original from the topic before conversion:

```
(ConsumerRecord) context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_RECORD)
```

Comment: Thanks Artem. Does ConsumerRecord.value provide the bytes that we get in listener method?

Comment: M-m-m. Might be. It is a result of the provided `Deserializer`